# How do I implement a circular buffer in a List of SelectListItems?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list that I populate based on the Enum I have created to load all the Months in a year. My key and value are set as Jan/01, Feb/02 etc.. If the current Month is Jan, then, I want DEC to be set to selected = true, if not the previous month set for selected = ture. How do I set the selected value

```
 List<SelectListItem> month = Framework.Enums.Month_List().Select(T => new          SelectListItem() { Text = T.Key, Value = T.Value.ToString() }).ToList();
        //make the previous month as "selected"
        int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
        if(currentMonth == 1) //which is Jan
```

now here I want to set Dec (12) as selected value, else have the previous month set.

TIA
Sue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be something like this?  Basically you have to catch the edge case of January.  The next part is simply finding the proper item in your list and setting it's selected property to True.

```
List<SelectListItem> month = Framework.Enums.Month_List().Select(T => new 
     SelectListItem() { Text = T.Key, Value = T.Value.ToString() }).ToList();
        //make the previous month as "selected"
        int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
        if(currentMonth == 1){
            month.Find(x=>x.Value == 12).Selected = true;
        }else{
           month.Find(x=>x.Value == ((currentMonth - 1).ToString())).Selected = true;
        }
        return month;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tommy , it complained about the "first()" method. Hence, changed my code to if (currentMonth == 1) { month.Find(x => x.Value == "12").Selected = true; } else { month.Find(x => x.Value == ((currentMonth - 1).ToString())).Selected = true; } but it's now complaining about "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Which part is giving you the null reference exception?  Also, for the First() issue, you will need to ensure that using System.Linq; is at the top of your class/controller :)  Find should work as well for what you need to do.  Are you sure that the text/values are being set properly in the SelectList List (and not reversed or empty?)  This would throw the null exception if nothing matches what is in your list...

Comment: System.Linq was listed, not sure why it would complain for First(). Yup, you were right, I had the values listed ast 01 for Jan, 02 for Feb etc..., but DateTime.Now.Month return 7 for July and not "07". thanks. how do you get the selected value stored to a variable

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean 'how do you get the selected value stored to a variable'.  If you mean in the current code block, you could do var selectedMonth = month.Find(x => x.Selected).Value;.  This is equivalent to saying, give me the item where Selected is true.  Keep in mind that at this point, if not careful, you can have more than one selected item in this list.  When it renders to the view, I think the first one will appear as the selected item.  When POSTed back, you will only get one value from the list :) Good luck!

Comment: @sue - BTW, I figured why it complained on the .First()...according to MSDN, .Find() returns the first match from the collection, so the First() in my example was redundant.  Thanks for editing to make the answer more correct :)